# Packaged kivy application opens new windows when multithreading

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, python-multiprocessing

I have made something with Kivy, here is the core code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

class UI(Widget):
    pass

class UIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.key_action)
        return UI()

    def key_action(self, *args):
        self.process()

    def on_start(self, **kwargs):
        pass

    def on_stop(self):
        raise SystemExit(0)

    def process(self):
        OtherFile.test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Builder.load_file('UI.kv')
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    UIApp().run()
```

As you see, I need the window import to get my keyboardhook.

OtherFile.test() however uses multi-threading. When that happens, new Kivy windows pop up non-stop. But it only happens if I package it into an exe, now while the script is executed normally. I have followed [this guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html) and have the folowing spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

import sys
from os import path
site_packages = next(p for p in sys.path if 'site-packages' in p)
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\GFuel\\PycharmProjects\\proj'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='AppName',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\GFuel\\PycharmProjects\\proj'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='AppName')
```

I compile with `PyInstaller AppName.spec -windowed -singlefile`
. The window itself works fine:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

But as soon as I press a key more and more windows start opening. My guess would be that for some reason `__name__` is `__main__` even when it shouldn't be (during multiprocessing) because of PyInstaller, but I don't know how to fix it.

Edit: I have proven this with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("YAY")
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Builder.load_file('UI.kv')
    UIApp().run()
```

YAY appears several times after I press a key. So in short, is there a way to make the packaged script work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

These have to be the first lines that are run in the main script. The script still uses all the threads it should, but works properly with an exe.